# Compare one col with another containing multiple entries

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

We need to compare one col with another in a df and identify if the entry from col"a" matches any of the entries in col"b". The result would be a new col with T = match or F = no match.

```
# task df
df <- data.frame(
  a = c("ABC", 'ABB', 'ACC', 'AAG'),
  b = c("XXC TTZ", "XCT ABB", "TTG WHO ACC", 'AAG')
)

# expected result
df <- data.frame(
  a = c("ABC", 'ABB', 'ACC', 'AAG'),
  b = c("XXC", "XCT ABB", "TTG WHO ACC", 'AAG'),
  match = c("F", "T", "T", "T")
)
```

I just come out of one year clinical rotation so my coding got a bit rusty. Could not find an answer here, excuse the hustle if this has been asked before. I guess the solution is rather straight forward but I can't wrap my head around it. Thanks a lot for helping (dplyr solutions much appreciated).

Answer (score 1):

Use `str_detect` from `stringr` which is vectorized for both string and pattern

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(match = str_detect(b, a))
    a           b match
1 ABC         XXC FALSE
2 ABB     XCT ABB  TRUE
3 ACC TTG WHO ACC  TRUE
4 AAG         AAG  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option

```
transform(
  df,
  match = mapply(grepl, a, b, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
)
```

gives

```
    a           b match
1 ABC     XXC TTZ FALSE
2 ABB     XCT ABB  TRUE
3 ACC TTG WHO ACC  TRUE
4 AAG         AAG  TRUE
```